# C#: Can you apply the ternary conditional operator (?:) to statements?

Tags: c#

I love C#'s ability to return an expression using the ternary conditional operator.  But I would like to execute a statement as opposed to merely returning an expression using a ternary conditional-like procedure; is there a way to do this?

```
//TRADITIONAL TERNARY CONDITIONAL (i.e., ?:):
a = isBob ? "Bob" : "Steve";

//HOW YOU WOULD WRITE MY PROPOSITION TRADITIONALLY:
if (isBob) { a = "Bob"; } else { b = "Steve"; }

//GOAL — HOW YOU WOULD LIKELY WRITE MY PROPOSITION USING THIS PROPOSED OPERATOR (e.g., !?!?):
isBob !?!? a = "Bob" : b = "Steve";
```

Is this possible, or is it just wishful thinking?  I am guessing it may be the latter, but I just wanted to make sure by first checking with C# veterans.  Thank you!

Comment: @CaiusJard I did—my mistake.

Comment: The most of  your  code can't  be even compilled

Comment: I just fixed the first line.  The second line should be fine, and the third has a non-existent operator I was just using as an example.

Comment: a="Bob" and b="Steve"  doesn' t make any sense  as a result of comparing. It is the same as to compare potatos and apples

Comment: @Serge I wasn't attempting to compare the statements; I was trying to execute one statement contingent on a separate boolean.

Comment: I understand it. What  I mean is I don' t see any practical use this is why it is not documented

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write this if you like, assuming you're getting mixed up between null coalescing and ternary

```
_ = isBob ? a = "Bob" : b = "Steve";
```

This will test the boolean isBob, and if true it will assign "Bob" to `string a` and return the result of the assignment into the discard (ie throw it away), similar for b if isBob is false. You have to do something with a ternary's value, but discarding it is an acceptable something..

It's unusual, and a bit more limited than a standard if/else (the true/false parts of the ternary would have to be same type or type-convertible between each other) or uglier (you could cast one of the assignment results to object, ugh)

```
//euww, objecfuscation?
_ = isBob ? (object)(a = "Bob") : b = 1;

//it's not so bad
if(isBob) a = "Bob"; else b= "Steve";
```

Comment: I was getting mixed up between null coalescing and ternary.  Thank you—it's strange they didn't make this capability of the operator more clear in their documentation.  I will accept your answer in 4 minutes as soon as I am able.

Comment: This pattern is a bit of a mix; the ternary is essentially an expression that returns a value ie `test ? value if true : value if false`, rather than a `test ? do if true : do if false` - if assignments in c # didn't return values then the code presented wouldn't work, but the fact that a value assignment returns the value that was assigned (except x++ etc) means we can put it in the ternary because technically it's "returning a value" even though it's "doing something". You could do the same with methods if they aren't void (`test ? NonVoidMethod1() : NonVoidMethod2()`)

Comment: The one I always wish for is conditional property setters eg `foo.(IsBob ? Bar : Baz) = value;`